# ASP.NET MVC View Models and binding analogs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

I have a good asp.net mvc background and I have recently started to learn Rails platform. 
I'm trying to map my asp.net mvc experience to Rails concepts and want to ask you a question:

Does Rails have the same cool binding feature that allows me to use View Model to display a form and bind form data after submit to a View Model? I'm a bit confused, because I do understand that all Rails models are actually ActiveRecord's model, not a something like POCO objects, but can I do this in Rails? Can I have my custom model (non ActiveRecord) and bind form's data to this model after form's submit.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if your custom model has an initializer function that accepts a hash as argument. That way you can create a form with the form_for tag and in the controller created a new object like so:

```
myObject = myObject.new(params[:myObject])
```

this will create a new object with the data from the hash, submitted by the form.
Ofcourse the initializer of your object needs to know which values are potentially available in the hash and extract them.

Your object could looks like this:

```
class MyObject

attr_accessor :prop1, :prop2, :prop3

def initialize(args = {})
self.prop1 = args[:prop1] if args.keys.contains(:prop1)
self.prop2 = args[:prop2] if args.keys.contains(:prop2)
self.prop3 = args[:prop3] if args.keys.contains(:prop3)
end

end
```

The above is a bit of pseudo code from ruby, but you should get the idea.